# generated midi note length

Tags: javascript, midi

I created some javascript code that generates midi files based on a passed note and octave. For the most part it works rather well. The problem is that the C note (note=0) plays much shorter than any other note (1 (C#) through 11 (B)).

Here is my code:

```
function play(note, octave, program){
    var note = (octave*12 + note).toString(16);
    var velocity = 'ff';
    var MIDI_DATA =
      'MThd%00%00%00%06%00%01%00%01%00%C0' + // midi header
      'MTrk%00%00%00%0E' + // track header
        '%00%C0%'+program+
        '%00%90%'+note+'%'+velocity+
        '%70%30%00' + 
        '%00%FF%2F%00'; 

    MIDI_DATA = btoa(unescape(MIDI_DATA));
    var e = document.createElement('embed');
    e.src = "data:audio/mid;base64,"+MIDI_DATA;
    e.type = "video/quicktime";
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    return e;
}
```

Why is a C note - play(0, 4, '18') sound so much shorter than any other - play(1, 4, '18')?
The pitch seems to be correct, just the note's play length.

I think it may have something to do with C being of value 0, but I don't know enough about what I'm doing here with midi to spot a problem.

NOTE: This code does not work in IE (any version).

Comment: And what happens when you call the midi file directly in the browser/quicktime without using the embed tag? Does it play the correct length of time?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior - all notes play for the same amount of time.  Update your QT version?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with my sound card. I tested on multiple OS/browser combinations, but not multiple computers. Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I should have checked this before.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, MIDI notes are played by giving a pitch and a velocity (i.e., loudness) between 1 and 127, and stopped by giving the same pitch with a velocity of 0.

Comment: You are right, codes above 127 are control codes, not data. The velocity should be `7f` rather than `ff`.

Answer (score 0):

When the note value is less than 16, you will end up with an invalid escape sequence, i.e. `%0` instead of `%00`. The `unescape` function will not turn that into a character, but leave it unchanged. As it is two characters instead of one, it spills over into the velocity byte and the rest of the MIDI code gets out of sync.

You can use code like this to format a number into two hexadecimal digits:

```
function toHex(n) {
  var code = '0' + n.toString(16);
  return code.substr(code.length - 2, 2);
}
```

Use it to make the note value two digits:

```
var note = toHex(octave*12 + note);
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa, but your provided code doesn't change anything. I forgot to mention, the cutoff only happens on the 4th octave.

Comment: When note has a hex value of '30' the note cuts off.